# what is the best way to visualize object state?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF grid bound a some object. I have 2 states for each object `State1` and `State2`.
`State1` corresponds to the value of one column and depending on the value, I change the row color between red, yellow, or white.

I have another state, `State2`, corresponding to whether the row is dirty, waiting, or synched to the remote object. I cannot use row color to indicate `State2` as it is already being used. What would be the best way to notify user for the state of `State2`?

I was thinking of adding a column with rectangles and change their colors but `State1` color change will interfere with column colors also. Another way i was thinking is to have a color change for the row name. Is this possible. How do people achieve this in their applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I think is to just make a column named "state2" or whatever and make it simply show the word that corresponds to the state information.

Then, on top of that, you have the option of adding color cues that change along with the text.

This way you never have to worry about the user not being able to tell the exact value of the information he/she is looking at.

Comment: i am putting in this solution right now but color notification is more visible than just text change. I guess i will change the text of the color as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to distinguish things without taking up too much space is icons. :)

Comment: an icon for each row? Though there aren't many rows so this maybe achievable. I will try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to coloring a row: the background color and the foreground (text) color.

The background colors vary red, yellow or white. If you can use a bold font, then font colors can provide the information.  Black for clean, gray for dirty would work.  The dirty rows' text would appear lighter, so they'd stand out.